# Как в React и Baobab обновить дерево после создания кокмпонента до первого рендера?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

React компонент, которому в props передан некий ID. По нему в дереве Baobab берутся данные для отображения этого компонента.

Данных именно по данному ID может не оказаться. Тогда надо их подменить на «загружается..» и инициировать асинхронное получение этих данных издалека. Именно заглушка в дереве нужна, т.к. другие компоненты в других местах могут почти одновременно появиться, с этим же значением ID. Надо избежать дублирования запросов одних и тех же данных.

**Вопрос:** как вписать эти временные данные с «загружается» именно в дерево, так, чтобы они уже использовались в первом же вызове метода `render()`?

---

Проверку на `exists` и запись заглушки я **пробовал** ставить:

- в конструктор компонента – там ещё не определены props;
- в `componentWillMount()` – но до рендера обновлённые данные не долетали, не смотря на `tree.commit()`;
- наконец, в обёртку `branch()`, где динамически создаю курсор для компонента на данные именно его ID – там вообще тормоза, и ошибка:

> Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я использую нечто подобное:

Создаём функцию загрузчик данных, которая выглядит примерно так:

```
var dataLoader = function() {
    getDataByAJAX();
    return null;
};
```

Узел дерева, который должен содержать требуемые данные, представляется в виде динамического узла или т.н. `monkey` ([подробнее](https://github.com/Yomguithereal/baobab/tree/v2#computed-data-or-monkey-business)) и выглядит примерно так:

```
data: {
    value: null,
    getData: monkey({
        cursors: {
            data: ['data', 'value']
        },
        get: function(data) {
            if (data.data === null) {
                return dataLoader();
            }
            return data.data;
        }
    })
}
```

В компоненте (я использую `mixin'):

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    mixins: [branch],
    cursors: ['data', 'getData']
});
```

Таким образом получается вот что:

При первом рендере мы получаем `null` и в этом случае выводим заглушку типа `<div>Загрузка...</div>`, при этом на фоне отправляем запрос на получение данных и после получения устанавливаем новое значение узла `data.value`, который в свою очередь вызовет обновление динамического узла, а тот вызовет `setState` внутри компонента и в следующем рендере компонент получит новые данные.

Надеюсь, понятно объяснил и это поможет или натолкнет на решение вашей задачи.

Comment: race condition: другой узел может захотеть те же данные, пока они ещё не загрузились. Хочется избежать дублей одного и того же ajax запроса – для этого пихать в дерево вместо отсутствующего узла какой-то "pending". У меня не получилось успеть прокинуть этот "pending" через дерево до первого рендера. У меня этот "pending: на самом деле строка типа "idтакой-то загружается". Пока приходится дублировать и создавать это значение в двух местах: и в мартышке (для аналогичных запросом из др. комп.), и в самом первом компоненте. Этого дублирования не получилось пока избежать.

Comment: Внутри функции-загрузчика можно ставить какой-то флаг, что запрос по данному ID уже отправлен.